# How to really plot a binary tree?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, trees

A binary tree is one that distinguishes left child from right child. However, in TreePlot you cannot specify which child is left, which is right, so the output is not a binary-looking tree. For example, what I want is

[image]

But the output using the following

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 6 -> 7, 4 -> 5}, Top, 1, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

is

[image]

Anyone can help with plotting a binary tree in Mathematica? Thank you!

Comment: If you're willing to do it in a completely brute force way, add in some extra children and surround your command with `FullForm[ ]`:  `FullForm[TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 6 -> 7, 6 -> "A", 
   4 -> "B", 4 -> 5}, Top, 1, VertexLabeling -> True, 
  DirectedEdges -> True]]`.  Then copy the resulting code and edit out the offending pieces.  (There's gotta be a better way.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is to somehow represent missing left and right nodes, but not to draw edges and vertices for those nodes. Something like this (not extensively tested):

```
maybeP = Except[nothing]|nothing
binaryTreeNodeP = {Except[nothing], maybeP, maybeP}

childOrEmptyNode[value:Except[nothing], nothing, side:(left|right)] := "empty" <> ToString[value] <> ToString[side]
childOrEmptyNode[Except[nothing], child:Except[Nothing], (left|right)] := child

binaryTreeNodeEdges[{v:Except[nothing], l:maybeP, r:maybeP}] := { v -> childOrEmptyNode[v, l, left], v -> childOrEmptyNode[v, r, right]}
makeBinaryTree[nodes:{binaryTreeNodeP..}] := Flatten[Map[binaryTreeNodeEdges, nodes]]

removeEmptyEdges = ( If[!StringMatchQ[ToString[#2[[2]]], "empty"~~__], {Darker[ Red], Arrowheads[{{Medium, 0.5}}], Arrow[#1]}]& )
removeEmptyVertices = ( If[!StringMatchQ[ToString[#2], "empty"~~__], {Background -> LightYellow, Inset[Framed[#2], #1]}]& )
```

Usage is simple:

```
nodes = {{1, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 4}, {6, 7, nothing}, {4, nothing, 5}}
TreePlot[makeBinaryTree[nodes], Top, 1, VertexRenderingFunction -> removeEmptyVertices, EdgeRenderingFunction -> removeEmptyEdges]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** An alternative approach to add invisible nodes and edges:

```
TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 6 -> 7, 
  Property[6->"7", EdgeShapeFunction -> None],
  Property[4->"5", EdgeShapeFunction -> None], 4 -> 5}, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> {_ -> "Square", "5" -> None, "7" -> None}, 
 VertexLabels -> {_ -> Placed["Name", Center], "5" -> None, "7" -> None}, 
 VertexSize -> .2, VertexStyle -> Orange]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

(Not to detract from Ivica M.'s excellent answer), you can also use `TreeGraph` and use the option `Properties` to specify whether a node is a left child or right child:

```
options = Sequence[VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexSize -> .2,  VertexStyle -> Orange];

tg = TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 6 -> 7, 4 -> 5}, 
  options, Properties -> {5 -> {"side" -> Right}, 7 -> {"side" -> Left}}]
```

And post-proces `tg` to adjust the coordinates of left-child and right-child nodes:

```
Fold[SetProperty[{##},  VertexCoordinates -> .25 {PropertyValue[{##}, 
         "side"] /. {Right -> 1, Left -> -1}, 0} + 
     PropertyValue[{##}, VertexCoordinates]] &, tg, 
 Select[VertexList[tg], PropertyValue[{tg, #}, "side"] =!= $Failed &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]