# Construct a binary tree where nodes are labeled according to given rule

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, trees, binary

I want to plot a binary tree in Mathematica where the nodes are labeled according to a given rule. In fact, whether a node has a left child or a right child or both, will be determined by a rule. And then I want to label each node according to some rule as well. How do I do that? I can accomplish this rather simply in programing languages such as Java/Kotlin. But Mathematica offers the advantage of a nice drawing and that's what I want (plus the rules are mathematical equations, etc.) How might I achieve this?

**Adding example**

By way of example, let's imagine it's a BST and a random function is generating the values. And the label of each node is a randomly chosen letter followed by the order in which that node was added, like "c7".

Comment: "...whether a node has a left child or a right child or both, will be determined by a rule. And then I want to label each node according to some rule as well." - it would be nice if you could give a concrete example of what you have in mind.

Comment: I've edited to specify an example. Does that help?

Comment: related Q/A: [How to really plot a binary tree?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128504/125)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to **plot** a binary tree

The solution I will present is specifically for *visualization*. It is *not* for constructing a data structure usable as a binary tree.

---

The following makes use of [`IGExpressionTree`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igexpressiontree) from my [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), version 0.4 of which is compatible with Mathematica 10.0 and later. Something similar could be implemented with [`ExpressionGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionGraph.html), available in Mathematica 12.1 and later only.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"];

i = 0;
makeVertex[] := RandomChoice@CharacterRange["a", "z"] <> IntegerString[i++]

treeNode[] := If[RandomReal[] > 1/2, makeVertex[], Null]

i = 0;
tree = FixedPoint[
   Replace[#, s_String :> s[treeNode[], treeNode[]], {-1}] &,
   makeVertex[]
  ];

g = IGExpressionTree[tree];

HighlightGraph[g,
 Subgraph[
  g,
  Pick[
   VertexList[g],
   First /@ IGVertexProp[VertexLabels][g],
   _String
  ]
 ],
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"
]
```

[image]

> And the label of each node is a randomly chosen letter followed by the order in which that node was added

`makeVertex` does this.

> whether a node has a left child or a right child or both, will be determined by a rule

This is the rule: `s_String :> s[treeNode[], treeNode[]]`. `treeNode[]` has a 50% change of being `Null`, which I used to represent no vertex. More precisely, no children will be added to `Null`, and it will be *present* in the final tree, but *hidden*. This is necessary to ensure that left/right children are drawn leftwards/rightwards, even if there is just one of them.

`IGExpressionTree` generates convenient vertex labels for us. We use these to identify which vertex is `Null`, and therefore needs to be hidden. `IGExpressionTree` wraps vertex labels in `HoldForm`, which is why we need `First` in `First /@ IGVertexProp[VertexLabels][g]`.